# Пытался сделать update с поиском но выскочила ошибка HTTP 404(Я использую Code First)

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

Захотел я сделать в своем проекте(Использующем  Code First.) возможность update с поиском . У меня в  проекте стартовым является представление Index.cshtml, и на нем ряд ссылок на методы . Идея в том, чтобы можно было ,нажав на строку" Update of planets with search" в стартовом  представлении , можно было выйти на новое представление, и в нем сначала в @Html.TextBox ввести id строки ,которую надо обновить ,потом заполнить формы для заполнения полей ,нажать "submit", и так  обновить.Когда я нажимаю на " Update of planets with search ",  у меня выскакивает ошибка HTTP 404. При этом в адресной строке вверху (Или, может быть, правильнее это называть окном браузера.) у меня никаких %20 нету.Вот представление Index.cshtml:

```
@{


Layout = null;


 }


  <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html>
   <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Solar System</title>
     </head>
     <body>
      <div>
      <h1>Solar System</h1>
       <p>Hello</p>
        <p><a href="/HomePlanet/IndexPlanet/">List of planets</a></p>

         <p><a href="/HomePlanet/SearchPlanet/">Search of planets</a></p>

         <p><a href="/HomePlanet/UpdatePlanetWithSearch/">Update of planets 
         with search</a></p>
         <p><a href="/InsertPlanet/InsertToPlanet/">Add  a planet</a></p>

         <p><a href="/HomeComet/IndexComet/">List of comets</a></p>
         <p><a href="/InsertComet/InsertToComet/">Add  a comet</a></p>

         <p><a href="/HomeSatellite/IndexSatellite/">List of satellites</a> 
        </p>
         <p><a href="/InsertSatellite/InsertToSatellite">Add  a  satellite</a> 
         </p>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Вот представление UpdatePlanetWithSearch.cshtml:

```
 @model SolarSystemThree.Models.Planet

@{
Layout = null;
 }


 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
  <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
   <title>Update a planet with search </title>
    </head>
```

```
    <h2>New  planet </h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdatePlanetWithSearch", "HomePlanet", FormMethod.Get))
    {

        @Html.TextBox("searching")<input type="submit" value="search" />
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Volume, "Volume")
        <br />
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Volume);
        <br /><br />

        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PlanetId)

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Weight, "Weight")
        <br />
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Weight)
        <br /><br />

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Diameter, "Diameter")
        <br />
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Diameter)
        <br /><br />
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DistanceEarth, "DistanceEarth")
        <br />
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DistanceEarth)
        <br /><br />
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DistanceSun, "DistanceSun")
        <br />
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DistanceSun)

        <br /><br />

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rotation, "Rotation")
        <br />
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rotation)
        <br /><br />

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RotationSun, "RotationSun")
        <br />
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RotationSun)
        <br /><br />

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, "Name")
        <br />
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        <br /><br />

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, "Description")
        <br />
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
        <br /><br />

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuantitySatellites, "QuantitySatellites")
        <br />
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuantitySatellites)
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    }
</div>
 </body>
  </html>
```

Вот два метода из  HomePlanetController:

```
    public ActionResult UpdatePlanetWithSearch(int? searching)
    {


        if (searching == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        Planet planet =db.Planets.Find(searching);
        if (planet != null)
        {
            return View(planet);
        }
        return HttpNotFound();


    }
    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult UpdatePlanetWithSearch(Planet planet)
    {


        db.Entry(planet).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("SuccessUpdatePlanet");


    }
```

Мы можете подсказать мне , как правильно делать  update с поиском в проекте, использующем Code First ?

Comment: Так, у вас `<a href="/HomePlanet/UpdatePlanetWithSearch/">`, то есть ссылка (GET) на адрес `site.ru/HomePlanet/UpdatePlanetWithSearch`, я вижу у вас два метода, один из который POST, а другой без тега с параметром `Id`. Вот хоть убейте, не помню как там по умолчанию, стоит ли атрибут нужный, попробуйте перейти по `site.ru/HomePlanet/UpdatePlanetWithSearch/1`, сработает?  Ну а вообще, попробуйте сделать нечто подобное: `[HttpGet("/UpdatePlanetWithSearch/{id?}")]`, так вы явно говорите, что id - это необязательный в пути параметр.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ,  я поместил над первым методом UpdatePlanetWithSearch ваше   [HttpGet("/UpdatePlanetWithSearch/{id?}")] , и студия подчеркнула это красным  и сообщила мне, что "HttpGetAttribute не содержит конструктор , который принимает аргументы  1".Также пытался ставить просто [HttpGet]. Тогда опять все провалилось с ошибкой HTTP 404. При этом все проваливается тогда, когда я нажимаю на ссылку на метод UpdatePlanetWithSearch в представлении Index .Я эту ссылку в этом представлении  копировал, потом удалял , потом опять вставлял тоже самое (Думал, может Razor у меня чудит.), никакого толку.

Comment: Также хочу сказать, что я пытался зайти через адресную  строку, тоже выскочила ошибка HTTP 404 .